# What happened to MooTouch?

Tags: mootools, touch

In March/April of this year there was [some talk](http://ajaxian.com/archives/mootouch) about a new mobile framework based on MooTools, MooTouch. It looked like a great and very promising alternative to jQTouch.

The framework was developed by Jacky Nguyen (see his [LinkedIn profile](http://sg.linkedin.com/in/nktpro)) who has apparently joined Sencha last July. He is not mentioned anywhere on the Sencha website though (there is a Jacky in the forums).

For a while one could register an email on http://www.mootouch.net/ with the promise of being contacted later. That website is now gone (the domain was registered by a "Nguyen, Khac Trung" who may or may not be the same "Jacky").

Is Sencha Touch based on MooTouch? (It doesn't look like it.) -- Or was MooTouch killed for fear it would compete with Sencha Touch?

...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jacky joined Sencha, and MooTouch is now part of Sencha Labs (probably integrated into Sencha Touch).

Sencha did blog about it here;
http://tumblr.com/xdtoj3t02

Comment: Ok thanks that's what I wanted to know! MooTouch seemed nicer than Sencha Touch, though... I think I'll use jQuery Mobile from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Currently another similar project would be MooTouch (also similar name) http://github.com/3n/MooTouch-Demo . This repo is currently only a demo which points to http://iancollins.me/MooTouch-Demo/ . The actual project is in a private repo which I think will be public once it's complete.

Answer (score 0):

This is the last, that I've heard from moo & mobile: http://github.com/cpojer/mootools-mobile. Still under construction.